# How can I count instances per day?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I want to use awk or other feature to count the number of instances per day but, each day I want to count only 1. I had try using uniq -c

But I can count how many in total.

For example:

```
 cat my.file
 SELMA   2015 03 21
 SELMA   2015 03 21
 BRUNO   2015 03 21
 BRUNO   2015 03 21
 BRUNO   2015 03 21
 HUGO    2015 03 28
 JESSY   2015 03 28
 JESSY   2015 03 28
 CHRIS   2015 03 29
 SELMA   2015 03 29
```

Using uniq -c I get

```
  SELMA 3
  BRUNO 3
  HUGO 1
  JESSY 2
  CHRIS 1
```

I would like to get

```
  SELMA 2
  BRUNO 1
  HUGO 1
  JESSY 1
  CHRIS 1
```

THis is probably easy but I am learning awk.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat my.file | sort | uniq | cut -d' ' -f 1 | uniq -c
```